Extracting applied styles from a component in react-native/expo
I have a specific use-case where I need to retrieve all the styles applied on a View/Pressable or any other component.
Is there an API or lifecycle method I can plug in to, to achieve this. e.g. onLayout, I already explored this avenue and there's no way to get what I want from here save the width and height of the View. I didn't get any luck either with StyleSheet.
Any solution is welcome. It doesn't have to be at runtime, it could be during build time or even an IDE hack, I do not mind any of these solutions so long as I can get access to the final composed style object generated by StyleSheet.
Thanks

You can create a custom hook or a wrapper component to log styles applied to a component.
